# Why Tailwind List Style type is not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have installed Tailwind CSS using npm, i am using `"tailwindcss": "^2.2.15"` version. when i am trying to apply list style type on my paragraph it's not working, it doesn't show any style type with content.

Here is my code which is running fine on `play.tailwindcss.com` [CODE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nrHwoURcgV)

But when i  write exact same code in my local code editor it doesn't work as intended.

Screenshot of exact same code when i run it locally.
[image]

Comment: Inspect your element that’s rendering incorrect. What does it say? Do they have the class you expected? What about the CSS file that’s loaded on the page? Does it have those style rules too?

Comment: when i checked inspect element, it shows list style type none, why is it so?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should find the answer in the [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) docs, more specifically [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#lists-are-unstyled).

As a solution you could add your own base styles to overwrite this default behavior in your `tailwind.css` file like so for all lists:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  ul, ol {
    list-style: revert;
  }
}
```

Or use tailwinds [utility classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type) to target specific lists.

Comment: "Ordered and unordered lists are unstyled by default" - I'm mindblown! Thanks for pointing out the link, Mattias!

Comment: I think `list-decimal list-outside pl-[revert]` is what I need.

Answer (score 6):

Add utility class "list-inside" also to the ul class.

```
<ul class="list-disc list-inside">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This correctly solves it but I don't know why it wasn't specified in the example in the docs to use list-inside, as list-disc was only used: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change default behavior globally then use class "list-disc" with padding-left "pl-3" or "list-disc" with "list-inside" . it will work.

```html
<ul class="list-disc pl-3">
<li>first item</li>
<li>first second</li>
</ul>

or

<ul class="list-disc list-inside">
<li>first item</li>
<li>first second</li>
</ul>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaC2P.png)